# Calling blade file with iframe in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I'm sorry for my bad english. I want to call list.blade.php with iframe in app.blede.php on my web page using laravel8 framework. Can anyone help me if I know what to do?

Comment: Please provide a code that you wrote, and learn how to [ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to add more illumination for use.

Comment: Have you considered an `@include` instead?

Comment: I have to do it with iframe

Comment: Then you'll need to add a route for `list.blade.php` to show up on, and iframe that into your other route's template.